# How to access GitHub Actions runner after CI/CD?

Tags: php, docker, apache, docker-compose, github-actions

I'm trying to deploy a PHP/MySQL app using GitHub Actions by implementing a CI/CD pipeline and unfortunately I cannot access the containers inside the runner, even though the pipeline executes perfectly without any issues. I tried using a simple bash script to print the IP of the runner but it still doesn't work.

Run ip=$(curl -s https://api.ipify.org)

The IP address of the runner is: 40.77.93.7

The IP address of the runner is: 40.77.93.7

I tried http://40.77.93.7:9090/
or http://40.77.93.7:3000/ but it says

"This site can’t be reached 40.77.93.7 took too long to respond."

Any ideas?

```
name: CI/CD Pipeline

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

env:
  IMAGE_NAME: sens31/ehospital

jobs:
          
  ip:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Get runner IP address
        run: |
          ip=$(curl -s https://api.ipify.org)
          for i in {1..10}; do
            echo "The IP address of the runner is: $ip"
          done      
          
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      
      - name: Log in to Docker Hub
        run: echo "${{ secrets.DOCKER_PASSWORD }}" | docker login -u ${{ secrets.DOCKER_USERNAME }} --password-stdin
        env:
          DOCKER_BUILDKIT: 1
      
      - name: Build and push Docker image
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v2
        with:
          context: .
          dockerfile: Dockerfile
          push: true
          tags: ${{ env.IMAGE_NAME }}:latest
          
  compose:
    needs: build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Clone repository
        run: git clone https://github.com/sensgithub/eHospital.git
        working-directory: ${{ github.workspace }}
      
      - name: Start services
        run: |
          cd eHospital
          docker-compose up -d

# Prometheus
  prometheus:
    needs: build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Start Prometheus
        run: |
          docker run -d --name prometheus -p 9090:9090 prom/prometheus

# Grafana 
  grafana:
    needs: build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Start Grafana
        run: |
          docker run -d --name grafana -p 3000:3000 grafana/grafana
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.4-apache

# Install required PHP extensions
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y libmariadb-dev
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli pdo pdo_mysql

# Copy application files to the container
COPY . /var/www/html/

# Copy Apache configuration file
COPY apache.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

# Enable Apache rewrite module
RUN a2enmod rewrite

# Install Docker Compose
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y curl && \
    curl -sSL https://get.docker.com/ | sh && \
    curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.29.0/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m) -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose && \
    chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose

# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /var/www/html

# Expose port 80
EXPOSE 80

# Start Apache server
CMD ["/usr/sbin/apache2ctl", "-D", "FOREGROUND"]
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.9'
services:

  db: 
    image: mysql:latest
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=ehospital
      - MYSQL_USER=ehospital
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=root
      - MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=1 
    volumes:
      - "./db:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d" # persistent db 
      
  www:
    image: php:apache
    volumes:
      - "./:/var/www/html" 
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443 # for future ssl traffic

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    ports:
      - 8001:80
    environment:
      - PMA_HOST=db
      - PMA_PORT=3306
```

Comment: It looks like you're trying to use the actions runner as a web host; that's not what they're for. You have to deploy to a third party.

Comment: @BenjaminW. Dang, should I do it on GitLab instead? Or that doesn't suffice either?

Comment: Both aren't web hosts; both have products to host static pages (GitHub Pages, GitLab Pages). To host a PHP/MySQL app, you need a hosting provider such as [Linode](https://www.linode.com/), [Hetzner](https://www.hetzner.com/), AWS, ...

Comment: @BenjaminW. Should I just use K8s then? I mean Linode, AWS, Azure, etc. will most likely charge me a lot and I'm on a "tight" budget.

Comment: These providers have plans as cheap as $5 or €2 per month. K8s sounds like total overkill, and you still have to host it somewhere anyway?